# how can i find suspicious files in linux

Tags: linux, security, ls

I'm trying to make my own ls.
Furthermore, I want to implement secure ls option which can find suspicious files in whole linux system. I have to make a decision with only two information.(location of file, file attribute)

How can i determine which file is suspicious?

I found some example.

ex)

- /dev/    setuid     # if there is setuid file in /dev, then warning
- /etc/    .file     # if there is file which is start with character '.' in /etc, then warning
- /        worldwritable    # If there is 777 permision file in whole directory
- /        setgid     # If there is setgid file file in whole directory

Please give me your idea!

(I think there is no right answer but i just want your reasonable idea)

Answer (score 1):

Well, *we* cannot tell you what files *you* consider "suspicious"...

Your description sounds like you want to implement a "rule catalog" you test all result entries against, but that is very vague. The general approach would be to feed each entry in the raw result of the file listing (what `ls` usually does) into some logic that applies all rules in the catalog to the entry. If one rule matches (comes out `true`), then you have a match. Sounds like a good example of a utility coded in C language with the rules coded in Lua (as plugins). That would offer great extensibility. HOwever keep in mind the extreme performance overhead you create!

Usually a different strategy is used: the package management on most Linux systems allows to decide if a file is "owned" by an installed package and if it has been modified. This could come in handy here: you check the "owning" package for each file in typical locations like `/etc`, `/var`, `/srv`, if it is *not* owned by any package, then *that* is what I would call suspicious, since it hints on a "wild installed package", so someone having bypassed the package management.